# How to install Unicorn on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, unicorn

I´m trying to install Unicorn server on my Mac with OS X Mavericks.

Every post explain the same, looks pretty simple, however is not working for me. I install the gem. But after that, I can´t run unicorn neither unicorn_rails because the files are not found.

See some logs:

```
gem install unicorn



Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed unicorn-4.8.3
Parsing documentation for unicorn-4.8.3
Installing ri documentation for unicorn-4.8.3
Done installing documentation for unicorn after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

unicorn_rails
-bash: unicorn_rails: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I just needed to restart the laptop.